# SQLite Foreign key setting

Tags: sqlite, firefox, foreign-keys

I am creating an SQLite database with SQLite Manager plug-in on Firefox.
When I create the database and I want to enable Foreign Keys I go to DB Settings and switch the "Foreign Keys" option to "On". When I change this it works perfectly

However when I close the database, and re-open it the setting is switched back to off. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is by design.

> Foreign Keys can be [enabled manually
>   for each database session](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/wiki/ForeignKeys) by going to
>   the DB Settings tab and setting the
>   Foreign Keys switch to ON.

Note that phrase "for each database session". This just follows the default behavior of SQLite itself, which doesn't provide a way to "set it and forget it".